# Count a number of rows in a dataframe per hour

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with two columns: timeStamp and eventMessage (string).

```
timeStamp:                                  eventMessage:
2020-10-19T10:07:56.7450775+02:00           transaction successful 
2020-10-19T10:08:13.025169+02:00            transaction successful
```

I want to end up with a dataframe that has two columns : hour and numberOfEvents per that hour.

```
 hour:     numberOfEvents:
 1         41
 2         0
 ...       ...
 24        32
```

I've tried the `df.resample('H', on='timeStamp', how='count')`, but I think the how='count' is deprecated now?

Is there a new quick pandas way to do it?

UPDATE: thanks to Ami Tavory's tip the df now looks like this:

```
timeStamp
10    792
11    792
14    594
15    198
16    198
```

I'm not actually sure if it's a dataframe with one column or some other type completely. And how do I fill in the hours that had zero events?

Miniupdate: It's pandas.core.series.Series

Converted it to df with:

```
series = df.message.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df.timeStamp).dt.hour).count()
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'hour': series.index, 'counted': series.values})
```

Now I just need to figure out how to add and fill in other hours from 1 to 24 that had no events with a zero.

Comment: you could `.groupby`

Comment: can you share a few more rows of your source data and expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your new question (after the edit).

> Converted it to df with:

You can more easily convert it with

`df = series.to_frame()`.

> Now I just need to figure out how to add and fill in other hours from 1 to 24 that had no events with a zero.

```
new_index = Index(arange(0,23,1), name="hour")
df.set_index("hour").reindex(new_index).fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Group by the hour, and count:

```
df.eventMessage.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df.timeStamp).dt.hour)).count()
```

Comment: Thanks! But I get the "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead". I'm a noob. Am I right at interpreting it as the temp data from the chain assignment isn't set to rows and columns?

Comment: Which line is giving you this warning? If you run just the code I suggested, do you get it?

Comment: Oh, you're right! It was an issue in a different line. Your code worked! I'll edit the question post because can't write the output here.